# How can I create a FabricJS eraser object from a PNG file?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, eraser

I have created fabric canvas and I know I can erase/recover canvas by using fabric.EraserBrush
But I would like to know if it is possible to load eraser from PNG (such as alpha mask or BW)
To load into Object.eraser?

I know I can use clipPath to clip canvas, but I would like to use eraserbrush.inverted functionality to recover.

I have tried using fabric.Eraser.fromObject to load from image but it does not create correct eraser object.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/8/Sample-Watermark.png', o => {
  fabric.Eraser.fromObject(o, a => {
    rect.eraser = a;
    rect.dirty = true;
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
});
```